# How to understand this code in terms of building and evaluating a stack?

Tags: python-2.7, stack

I was recently trying to solve a challenge on Hackerrank which asked us to figure out whether a string containing brackets (e.g. {}, (), and [] ) was balanced or not (source: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/balanced-brackets). I wanted to solve this using the following approach that also integrated the initial format Hackerrank provided:

```
import sys

def isBalanced(s):
     #insert code here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = int(raw_input().strip())
    for a0 in xrange(t):
        s = raw_input().strip()
        result = isBalanced(s)
        print result
```

I should also note that site has configured the following as being the standard input in order to test the functionality of the code:

```
3
{[()]}
{[(])}
{{[[(())]]}}
```

In order to get the following output:

```
YES
NO
YES
```

However, I didn't understand how to approach this code, chiefly because I did not understand why Hackerrank used the `if __name__ == "__main__":` clause, as I thought that this clause was only used if someone wanted their module to be executed directly rather than executed through being imported in another script (source: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do?rq=1)). I also did not understand the for loop containing `for a0 in xrange(t):` since `a0` is not used within the for loop for anything, so I'm really unsure how the standard input would be processed.

So I ended up looking up the solution on the discussion page, and here it is below:

```
lefts = '{[('
rights = '}])'
closes = { a:b for a,b in zip(rights,lefts)}

def valid(s):
    stack = []
    for c in s:
        if c in lefts:
            stack.append(c)
        elif c in rights:
            if not stack or stack.pop() != closes[c]:
                return False
    return not stack  # stack must be empty at the end

t = int(raw_input().strip())
for a0 in xrange(t):    
    s = raw_input().strip()    
    if valid(s):
        print 'YES'
    else:
        print 'NO'
```

This code also confuses me, as the writer claimed to utilize a data structure known as a "stack" (although it seems to be just a Python list to me). And although the writer removed the `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement, they retained the `for a0 in xrange(t):`, which I'm not sure how it processes the standard input's integer and corresponding strings.

Furthermore, although the `isBalanced` function confuses me because it returns `not stack`. In a hash comment on the `return` statement of the function, the writer also states the `# stack must be empty at the end`. What does that mean? And how could this list be empty if, during the clause `if c in lefts:`, the stack is appended with the character of the string that is being iterated in the for-loop. So why would the function return `not stack`? Wouldn't it be consistent to `return True` so that the function would act as a Boolean tester (i.e. would return true if a certain object adhered to certain criteria, and false if the the object did not)?

I am still relatively new to coding so there are a lot of principles I am not familiar with. Can anyone illuminate as to how this would work?

Answer (score 0):

iam not sure how your code works ..  if **name** == "**main**": do?). just exlained where you use of Before executing the code, it will define a few special variables. For example, if the python interpreter is running that module (the source file) as the main program, it sets the special **name** variable to have a value "**main**". If this file is being imported from another module, **name** will be set to the module's name